# На каком уровне должен располагаться репозиторий git, venv и requirements.txt в django-проекте?

Tags: django, git, venv, requirements.txt

Всем привет!

Подскажите, на каком уровне мне создавать репозиторий git?

на уровне project_26072023

или в самом проекте, который я создан в django - myproject

и где правильно располагать папку с виртуальным окружением и файл requirements.txt

Спасибо!

[image: Иерархия моего проекта]

Comment: Где вам удобно, там и располагайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лично я делаю так:

```py
| <какой-то каталог>
|__
   | <проект Django>  # (то, что создаёт `django-admin startproject ...`)
   | venv
   | .gitignore
   | requirements.txt
```

То есть каталог `venv` и файлы `.gitignore` и `requirements.txt` располагаются *рядом* с Django-проетом, а не в его каталоге.

Хотя здесь, скорее всего нет какого-то однозначно правильного решения. Делайте как вам удобно.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне важно понять, как это в реальных проектах, чтобы привыкать сразу к хорошему. И git получается тоже в <каком-то каталоге>, а не в папке с проектом

Comment: @Алекс, да репозиторий git в том же каталоге, что и файл `.gitignore`. Если вам помог этот ответ, отметьте его как "принятый" (серая галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Спасибо, Вы ответили ещё на один мой вопрос - Как благодарить в stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Алекс, благодарить можно ещё и стрелочкой вверх :)